# Fixed positioned Div with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Fixed positioned DIV whose content is appended using jquery.

When its height become greater than the screen size i cant see the contents at the bottom of the DIV.

To see the lower down i need to use zoom tool of the browser.

Is it possible that div becomes scrollable if its height increased than a specific limit.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Example of the problem would be nice. ( http://www.jsfiddle.net )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `max-height` CSS property on the div, and it will increase to be no larger than the value you specify.  Then set `overflow: auto` to make it scrollable when content is outside of the viewable area.

Answer (score 0):

Use css to get scrolling functionality:
`overflow: scroll`

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class to div

try this ..

```
.className
    {
       height:100px;  \* default hight of the div*\
       overflow: auto;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

set `height: auto;` If you want to have minimum height to x then you can write

```
height:auto;
min-height:30px;
height:auto !important;        
height:30px;
```

Answer (score 0):

just set max-height for the div

```
*html yourdiv { 
   height: expression( this.scrollHeight > 332 ? "333px" : "auto" ); /* sets max-height for IE */
   overflow:auto;
}
yourdiv{
   max-height: 333px; /* sets max-height value for all standards-compliant browsers */
   overflow:auto;
}
```